# How to get exact Search volumes for google Keywords?

Tags: google-ads-api, google-search-api, keyword-search

I have a set of keywords for an idea, I have put those keywords to the Google planner and i get search volume in ranges but I want exact search volumes for those keywords like ubersuggest is giving us. I wonder how an individual can achieve this?

Comment: off-topic, if you are building an SEO tool let me know.